# Disable input field when submit button is cicked

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to disable a input field as soon as submit button is click. The angular way suggest this:

here button is disabled when check box is checked. same way I need to disable the input field when I click button.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="check"> </input>
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="check">Checkbox to be disabled</input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IJust set/reset the variable triggering disabled on input field in the click event of button:

```
  Search : <input ng-model="query" ng-disabled="isDisabled"  />
  <button ng-click="isDisabled = true;">Name</button>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4YtLu/108/

Comment: The code is correct. But the fields don't reset back on unchecking the checkbox. Instead of ng-click="isDisabled = true;" , use ng-model="isDisabled"

Comment: True. But I assume the OP only wanted to disable the input post submit and then follow some progression as per need. But yes, good thought

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="isDisabled">Checkbox to be disabled</input>
```

in your controller, on submit set

```
$scope.isDisabled=true;
```